# How can change font size on a report of odoo14 , like sales order of purchasing order

Tags: odoo

I want to optimze a extenal report of PDF file that print out from odoo14, but I don't konw how to to change the font size. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to identify which report you need to change, you can find the list of reports in odoo by going to 'Settings >> Technical(Menu) >> Reports(under Reporting)'.

Once you find your report, one of the way is inline-css:

You can directly add style in page, like this one

' div class="page" style="font-size: 15px !important;" '